# Repeated image requests between routes

Tags: reactjs

When routing between pages, images are loaded every time, is it possible to cache them? Even if I return to an already loaded page, there is a request for an image.

I have small app

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Router>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/">To Home</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/profile">To Profile</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/profile/andrew" exact>To Andrew's Profile</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/feed">To Feed</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
          <Route exact path="/profile" component={ProfilePage} />
          <Route path="/profile/:username" component={ProfileDetailPage} />
          <Route path="/feed" component={FeedPage} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And in the FeedPAge I have this code

```
export function FeedPage() {
  return (
    <div>
      <svg><use href={`sprite.svg#favorite`} /></svg>
      <h1>Feed Page!</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

When I routing between pages, I always see requests to http://localhost:3000/sprite.svg

How can I cache this?

[image]

Comment: You could try returning `maxage` and `immutable` cache control headers from the server

Comment: Unless you are actively preventing it, there's a good chance the users browser will already cache the image. To be clear, the dev-tools will still show a network request for cached content in Chrome dev-tools, but the "size" column will say something like "memory cache" (Also, make sure the dev-tools setting to disable the cache is turned off)

Comment: No, in safari in prod I especially see flickering of my image (the time when image requests are made)